# Diretório Subreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Estou com problemas na localização do subreport, quando estava usando o projeto local ele funcionava perfeitamente, mas agora que passei para o servidor ele não está localizando o subreport. Estou tentando usar assim:

```
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[""]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

O subreport está na mesma pasta do relatorio principal, como faço para ele buscar na mesma pasta?

Answer (score 0):

No seu relatório, selecione o subrelatório e em seguida vá em Propriedades. Na seção "Subreport Properties", verifique o atributo "Subreport Expression".

Se tiver com "P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + seuRelatorio.jasper" você deverá remover o parâmetro SUBREPORT_DIR, deixando apenas "seuRelatorio.jasper".

Comment: Cara, eu testes dessa forma antes mesmo de postar aqui e não deu certo não. Oq deu certo para mim foi colocar o caminho do servidor no diretório